# A simple, quick method to extract a single value in a dataframe based on an adjacent column contents

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following `.txt` file, read in as such.

```
abc <- "           V1                   V2
1               Version                        2.1
2               StationName               AngryFly
3               BeginTime      2019-14-07.21:21:00
4               EndTime        2019-14-07.22:21:00
5               IgnoreNo                     50000
6               PumpedVolume         notCalculated
7               NoSamples                      500
8               NoPickable                  107515
9               Ignored                          0"

# Plus a few more excluded rows


df <- read.table(text = abc, header = TRUE)
```

I have had a good look around and have managed an totally overcomplicated solution but there must be a better way.

I am looking to extract `as.numeric` the `NoPickable`.

I want the following:

```
> print(NoPickable)
[1] 107515
```

Many thanks

Comment: I think they're factor and you might want to do `as.numeric(as.character(df$V2[df$V1=="NoPickable"]))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your problem is that R by default reads the second column V2 as `factor`.

Do:

```r
df <- read.table(text = abc, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And then:

```r
as.numeric(df$V2[df$V1=="NoPickable"])
```

or in `tidyverse`:

```r
df %>% filter(V1 == "NoPickable") %>% pull(V2) %>% as.numeric()
```

Comment: fantastic, thank you. The issue I have is the text file when read in has some characters I cannot see, is there anyway to do a partial match, maybe ```filter(V1 == grep("NoPickable")

Comment: I have it working by entering in ```V1 == "NoPickable   "```, not an ideal solution

Comment: @Jim you could `df %>% filter(str_detect(V1, "NoPickable")) %>% pull(V2) %>% as.numeric()`